# Android httpResponse connection /127.0.0.1:8080;LocalPort=36133(0)

Tags: android, httpresponse

I am doing [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) tutorial with some differences.

But i am having some problems. First i was having IIS(Internet Information Services) so i changed the `httpd.conf` to the port 8080.

On the android program I set the url to:

```
localhost/android_connect/get_all_products.php
```

But i cannot run the program.It keeps giving me errors on

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

My log is giving me this errors:

```
03-21 05:56:24.864: D/libc-netbsd(3966): getaddrinfo: localhost  return error = 0x8 >>

03-21 05:56:24.867: D/libc-netbsd(3966): getaddrinfo: localhost get result from proxy >>

03-21 05:56:24.869: I/System.out(3966): [socket][0] connection /127.0.0.1:8080;LocalPort=60338(0)

03-21 05:56:24.870: I/System.out(3966): [CDS]connect[/127.0.0.1:8080] tm:90

03-21 05:56:24.871: D/Posix(3966): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.oss :8080 

03-21 05:56:24.873: I/System.out(3966): [socket][1:60338] exception

03-21 05:56:24.875: I/System.out(3966): [CDS]close[60338]

03-21 05:56:24.877: I/System.out(3966): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:60338]

03-21 05:56:24.880: W/System.err(3966): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to localhost:8080 refused

03-21 05:56:24.881: W/System.err(3966):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [a quick google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099347/org-apache-http-conn-httphostconnectexception-connection-to-http-localhost-re) : Use `http://10.0.2.2:8080/` as your ip address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I guess you are running your application on an emulator so actually the `localhost` now pointing to you emulator which is not the server. Therefore, the connection can't be established and cause the error.

Instead of using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as your server address, try using your PC IP as the server address, you can find the IP on the cmd with the command: `ipconfig /all`

Hope this help.

Comment: I am doing with my cellphone .I tried with my IP and i had the same problem.

03-21 15:58:44.125: I/System.out(7505): [socket][0] connection /192.168.56.1:8080;LocalPort=49024(0)

03-21 15:58:44.127: I/System.out(7505): [CDS]connect[/192.168.56.1:8080] tm:90

03-21 15:58:44.130: I/System.out(7505): [socket][1:49024] exception

03-21 15:58:44.130: I/System.out(7505): [CDS]close[49024]

03-21 15:58:44.131: I/System.out(7505): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:49024]

03-21 15:58:44.133: W/System.err(7505): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.56.1:8080 refused

Answer (score 0):

you may try 10.0.2.2 instead of 127.0.0.1.