# Android connection: refused

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an Android app that requests to server but whenever i try to request the server it gives me the following error:

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to
>
> > http://    10.10.10.129:80
>
> refused

don't know how to fix it and I've tried a lot of things but it didn't worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099347/org-apache-http-conn-httphostconnectexception-connection-to-http-localhost-re...,see here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you give internet permission to your up in manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and I think that address is local ip so you can use just `10.10.10.129` 
if you give more detail about your app I can help you.

thanks

Comment: i ahve already mentioned that in my minifest file . and also it  tried 10.10.10.129 but still not working.

Comment: can you try it on your browser?

Comment: the more details are that i have my APIs on a server that is directly linked with the database and from android i use to access it. it use to work but today don't know what happened its not working...

Comment: I am sorry I cant understand, it is working for a long time but only today it is not working ? do i understand right?

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" means that there is nothing listening on the specified port.

So first check that you have the correct address and it's reachable from your device and there's a server running in port 80.