# how to connect android with php mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am using android code to get the json data from my localhost database. I am using xampp. I am able to the the json value when I run the it on my system but I am my emulator fails to get  those value. The crashes I have a option force to close. I tried all the url to my knowlegde but I can't find a solution. The present url I am using now is `http://localhost/android_connect/get_all_products.php` and I am getting an error in Logcat `localhost is refused`. Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Comment: This is a dupliate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760585/accessing-localhostport-from-android-emulator. There has a good answer :)

Comment: refer this link It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099347/org-apache-http-conn-httphostconnectexception-connection-to-http-localhost-re          -----------  https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=SRFOU5vOD8KW8QfPh4DABQ#q=how+to+connect+android+with+php+mysql+using+xampp

Answer (score 0):

**Hey there,**

*It is stating that the XAMPP server is not started and listening on Port no : 80
Because default port for HTTP is 80.
This states the error*

> localhost connection refused.

Try restarting the server.Also check that android emulator is excluded from windows firewall(Only in windows)