# value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject In Android Programming

Tags: java, android

When I am Create new Android Application to Fetch data from my server like xampp, But Its not Retrieval and i am using catch statement for itz exception then it says as JSONObject cannot convert it, How to Solve?

Solution for this, Please Help me?
Thanks in Advance

My Full Java Code

```
   package com.example.fetch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Disp extends Activity {
    TextView user,email,phone;
    String abdu,hos,em,ph;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.disp);
        user=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.user);
        email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
        phone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.phone);
        SharedPreferences sandra=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("veena", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        abdu=sandra.getString("shyma", "");
        user.setText(abdu);
        aji aj=new aji();
        aj.execute();
    }
    class aji extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                DefaultHttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();
                ResponseHandler<String> res=new BasicResponseHandler();
                HttpPost postMethod=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/std/ret.php");
                List<NameValuePair>nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",abdu));
                postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                 hos = hc.execute(postMethod,res);
                 System.out.println(hos);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error:"+e);
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Login",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            parsingmethod();
        }
    }



    public void parsingmethod()
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject(hos);
            JSONObject jobject1=jobject.getJSONObject("Event");
            JSONArray ja=jobject1.getJSONArray("Details");
            int length=ja.length();
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
            {
                JSONObject data1=ja.getJSONObject(i);

                em=data1.getString("email");
                ph=data1.getString("pass");

                System.out.println(em+ph);
                email.setText(em);
                phone.setText(ph);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            /*System.out.println("error:"+e);
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
            e.printStackTrace();
            displayExceptionMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
        }



    private void displayExceptionMessage(String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }
```

Catch Exception Shows that value

My Log Cat

```
01-20 16:22:31.432: I/System.out(10797): Error:org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused
01-20 16:22:31.452: I/System.out(10797): error:java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 16:24:01.342: I/System.out(10996): error:org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 16:44:57.302: I/System.out(11503): error:org.json.JSONException: No value for Event
01-20 16:50:19.062: I/System.out(11741): error:org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 16:50:59.572: I/System.out(11960): error:org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 16:50:59.572: E/Fail 2(11960): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 16:51:26.462: I/PGA(12155): New SOCKET connection: m.example.fetch (pid 12155, tid 12155)
01-20 16:51:29.142: I/System.out(12155): error:org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 16:51:29.142: E/Fail 2(12155): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 16:51:49.742: I/System.out(12347): error:org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 16:51:49.742: E/Fail 2(12347): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 16:52:11.062: I/System.out(12540): error:org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 16:52:11.062: E/Fail 2(12540): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp.parsingmethod(Disp.java:86)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:76)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:1)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-20 17:05:45.082: W/System.err(13814):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 17:05:51.882: W/System.err(13814): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 17:05:51.882: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-20 17:05:51.882: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
01-20 17:05:51.882: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp.parsingmethod(Disp.java:86)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:76)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:1)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-20 17:05:51.892: W/System.err(13814):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp.parsingmethod(Disp.java:86)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:76)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:1)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-20 17:06:26.712: W/System.err(13814):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 17:07:20.232: W/System.err(13814): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp.parsingmethod(Disp.java:86)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:76)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:1)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-20 17:07:20.242: W/System.err(13814):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp.parsingmethod(Disp.java:86)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:76)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:1)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-20 17:07:40.612: W/System.err(13814):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 17:11:44.152: W/System.err(13814): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 17:11:44.152: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp.parsingmethod(Disp.java:86)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:76)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:1)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-20 17:11:44.162: W/System.err(13814):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 17:12:13.872: E/dalvikvm(13814): No JIT support for bytecode f0 at offsetPC 0
01-20 17:12:13.872: E/dalvikvm(13814): JIT implementation not found
01-20 17:12:13.872: I/dalvikvm(13814): codeGenBasicBlockJit returns negative number
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp.parsingmethod(Disp.java:86)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:76)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:1)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-20 17:12:13.892: W/System.err(13814):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp.parsingmethod(Disp.java:86)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:76)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:1)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-20 17:13:12.522: W/System.err(13814):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 17:19:47.832: I/PGA(14194): New SOCKET connection: m.example.fetch (pid 14194, tid 14194)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at com.example.fetch.Disp.parsingmethod(Disp.java:86)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:76)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:1)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-20 17:19:50.772: W/System.err(14194):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at com.example.fetch.Disp.parsingmethod(Disp.java:86)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:76)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:1)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-20 17:22:24.402: W/System.err(14194):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 17:32:17.792: W/System.err(14194): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-20 17:32:17.792: W/System.err(14194):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-20 17:32:17.792: W/System.err(14194):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
01-20 17:32:17.792: W/System.err(14194):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
01-20 17:32:17.792: W/System.err(14194):    at com.example.fetch.Disp.parsingmethod(Disp.java:86)
01-20 17:32:17.792: W/System.err(14194):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:76)
01-20 17:32:17.792: W/System.err(14194):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:1)
01-20 17:32:17.792: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-20 17:32:17.792: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-20 17:32:17.802: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-20 17:32:17.802: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:32:17.802: W/System.err(14194):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:32:17.802: W/System.err(14194):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-20 17:32:17.802: W/System.err(14194):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:32:17.802: W/System.err(14194):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:32:17.802: W/System.err(14194):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-20 17:32:17.802: W/System.err(14194):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-20 17:32:17.802: W/System.err(14194):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My PHP Page

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$user=$_REQUEST['user'];
$sql1=mysql_query("select * from reg_table where user='$user'")or die (mysql_error());
$c = mysql_num_rows($sql1);
while($sql2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{
$arrDet['Event']['Details'][]=$sql2;
}
if($c>0)
{
$arrDet['Details']['status']="success";
}
else
{
$arrDet['Details']['status']="Nodata";
}
echo json_encode($arrDet);
?>
```

Main Logcat Error

```
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at com.example.fetch.Disp.parsingmethod(Disp.java:86)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:76)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at com.example.fetch.Disp$aji.onPostExecute(Disp.java:1)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-20 17:47:26.442: W/System.err(14954):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the logcat error output and your `JSON`.

Comment: i think you are using PHP as server side, and this `<br ...` is an error in php page you are calling, so check ur server side code

Comment: the error message "<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted ... " indicates that what you get back from the server is not JSON at all.

Comment: On which of the calls to `getJSONObject` does this occur?

Comment: @SignoffTeamz please edit your question to add code and logcat. It is quite unreadable in comments.

Comment: Any one Please help me? @Yazan

Comment: `Connection to http://localhost refused` ..

Comment: No @Haceto, It is Worked Correctly Becase my Hiting Php shows Result

Comment: @SignoffTeamz I only highlighted the main Error in your Logcat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099347/org-apache-http-conn-httphostconnectexception-connection-to-http-localhost-re)

Comment: @Hecketo It is not good choice it cannot working for me

Comment: what happen if you open the page URL you are getting json from inside a web-browser (on ur desktop)? also what is the code you are using to call that page, it might have some issues, some parameters are not sent maybe?

Comment: what i can see, in your java code, you are sending http-param `username` but in your PHP page you are reading param name `user` `$_REQUEST['user']` i think this may cause an issue... it will be like NULL in php ? try to use same name on both Java and PHP.

Comment: @Yazan Thanks Buddy.Itz Working

Comment: good i will post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search a lot and find a way

```
$user=$_REQUEST['user'];
```

Php change to

```
$user=$_REQUEST['username'];
```

Will work Perfectly..

Thanks to Yazen

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3604083/yazan

Answer (score 2):

what i can see, in your java code, you are sending http-param `username` but in your PHP page you are reading param name user `$_REQUEST['user']` i think this may cause an issue... it will be like NULL in php ?

try to use same name on both Java and PHP
you need to change the line in android as below

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user",abdu));
```