# I am making a simple login check application

Tags: android, json, httpconnection

when i am trying to run my application through an android device i gets the error as

```
Error in http connection org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.0.105 refused.
```

I am using same network for my computer and device.
in my mainactivity i have

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://"+ip+"//Zeditsho_app/login.php");                          

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));                           

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);                           

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

and my ipconfig activity is

```
public class IpconfigActivity {
    public static String ip="192.168.0.105";

}
```

could anyone help me to sort out this?

Comment: internet permission added ? and why double slash before Z "//Zeditsho_app"

Comment: Have you activated Wamp or something like on your computer?

Comment: yes .i added internet permission. actually i got this code from internet as an example to login check

Comment: Check whether the URL is working or not in postman or Advanced rest client tool in chrome.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099347/org-apache-http-conn-httphostconnectexception-connection-to-http-localhost-re

Comment: @Hari_krish4 is ri8 ,the url you are requesting is not valid , first try to connect using any rest client and check weather you are getting response or not in browser ?

Comment: sorry I am not familier with that tool.when i check the url in my browser it worked

Comment: Please check that you are running the android device over same network.

Comment: Please check firewall is blocking request from mobile?

Comment: Firewall is off in my system.and my device and systems are in same network..but still i got the error..what to do